# appenChild() is not working in my you tube chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I have write two function in my content.js file.(chrome extension for you tube)
finding element through "tag" name (document.getElementsByTagName).
after this i used it in two function but it is not working in second function while appending child in this tag.Below you get the two function

This is not working:

```
function buttond(){
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   var ge=document.getElementsByTagName("ytd-compact-video-renderer")[i];
   var node=createElement("button");
   var text=createTextNode("click");
    node.appendChild(text);
    ge.appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

But this is working WHY??

```
function butstop(){
var i=0;
 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   var ge=document.getElementsByTagName("ytd-compact-video-renderer")[i];
      if(ge && ge.style.display=="none"){
         ge.style.display="block";
}
     else if(ge){
    ge.style.display="none";

 }

}
}
```

Final work i am doing is adding play-next button given in below image link.

[image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9252491/23092764/0427fb98-f5f8-11e6-8b21-d46ddc7cdd76.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
   var node=createElement("button");
   var text=createTextNode("click");
```

You need to change this to:

```
   var node=document.createElement("button");
   var text=document.createTextNode("click");
```

After this, it will work fine.

Edit: [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/x7kc6uo6/7/)

Comment: It works.Thanks a lot for identifying my this silly mistake.